# How can I access a dataframe that is returned in another function (Python)

Tags: python, dataframe, function, return

How my code works is in two steps.

I have one file called filter.py which filters my dataframe according to inputs. In this file there is a function update_df() which returns data_filtered

```
def update_df(ToEmail, FromEmail, ToJob, FromJob, Date):
    FromEmailF = (data['fromEmail'] == FromEmail)
    ToEmailF = (data['toEmail'] == ToEmail)
    FromJobF = (data['fromJob'] == FromJob)
    ToJobF = (data['toJob'] == ToJob)
    DateF = (data['date'] == Date)
    Filter = (FromEmailF & ToEmailF & FromJobF & ToJobF & DateF)
    data_filtered = data[Filter]
    return data_filtered
```

In another file, I need to access this data_filtered.
I first imported update_df but I can't figure out how I can take data_filtered from the function.
I tried the following

```
def datafilter(data_filtered):
    df = data_filtered
    return df
```

but now I can't access df either no matter what I do. I just need a way to get the dateframe itself. I hope any of you guys can help me and I can provide more info if needed.

Answer (score 1):

update_df returns a dataframe, just set a variable to the return of the update_df when you call it

```
from filter import update_df
df = update_df(ToEmail, FromEmail, ToJob, FromJob, Date)
```

I would also rename your script `filter.py` to something else as `filter` is already a used word in python

Comment: Would that mean I would have to import those from filter.py as well?

Comment: yes, at the start of your script you would have import filter and then you would call filter.update_df